# When can I discard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm curious I started magic with my mother yesterday and she doesn't like house rules only official rules. Can I discard a card from my hand and draw a card from my library?

Comment: It would beat the purpose of [One with Nothing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=88817)

Answer (score 14):

Discard at will? No. You either discard when instructed by a game rule (more cards than hand size at the end of your turn), when instructed by an ability (such as [Enhanced Awareness](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enhanced%20Awareness)'s), or to pay a cost (such as for [Rummaging Goblin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rummaging%20Goblin)'s ability). If you aren't instructed to discard, you can't. Similarly, you can't just draw a card to replace any card you discard.

Answer (score 3):

You only draw one card during your draw step. At the end of your turn, if you have more than 7 cards in hand, you must discard until you have 7 cards in hand. These are standard rules that always apply unless a spell or ability commands you to do otherwise. When discarding you are not allowed to redraw to replace the card unless a spell or ability allows you to do so. [Library of Leng](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Library%20of%20Leng), [Anvil of Bogarden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Anvil%20of%20Bogarden), [Grafted Skullcap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grafted%20Skullcap), [Heightened Awareness](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heightened%20Awareness) are examples of spells that affect how you draw and discard.

Comment: You can also discard a card to pay a cost (such as for Rummaging Goblin's ability). I'm not sure how to add that to your answer.